# "Hamiltonicity" of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected simple undirected graph. A *way* in $G$ is a function $w:\{1,\ldots, n\}\to V(G)$ for some positive integer $n$, such that $\text{im}(w) = V(G)$, and for all $k\in \{1,\ldots, n-1\}$ we have $\{w(k), w(k+1)\} \in E$.

We define the *hamiltonicity* of $G$ by $$H(G) = \min\{n\in\mathbb{N}:\text{ there is a way } w:\{1, \ldots n\}\to V(G)\} - |V(G)|.$$

(A connected graph is Hamiltonian if and only if $H(G) = 0$.)

Is it true that for all connected graphs we have $H(G) \leq |V(G)| - 1$? Or can $H(G)$ become larger, even arbitrarily large with respect to $|V(G)|$?

Comment: What prevents a *way* to cover $V(G)$ multiple (arbitrarily many) times, like : $0\to 1 \to0\to 1 \to0\to 1 \to0\to 1 \to...$?

Comment: "A [....] if and only if [...]" is _false_ since you did not require your _way_ to be _closed_, i.e., to have $w(1)=w(n+1)$, and since _hamiltonian_ is most often taken to mean "has a Hamilton _circuit_". The standard term for has a Hamilton _path_ is _traceable_. It will improve the question if you edit it to use standard terminology: your_ways_ would usually be called _walk_ which visits every vertex at least once. And you should clarify whether you are intentionally only asking for Hamilton _paths_ and not for Hamilton _circuits_.(Otherwise, add in a closedness-condition.)

Comment: For readability, in a separate comment, the usual conventions nowadays are: _alternating sequence of vertices and edges_ = _walk_, _such a thing without edge-repetitions_ = _trail_, _such a thing with neither edge- nor vertex-repetitions_ = _path_.

Comment: Sorry, correction, you actually did require closedness.

Comment: @PeterHeinig Where does he require closedness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$H(G)\leq \lvert V(G)\rvert-1$ for every finite connected graph.

Proof. Consider any spanning tree $T$ of $G$, double every edge of $T$, choose any Euler tour $W$ of this auxiliary graph, consider the projection $\mathrm{p}(W)$ of $W$ to $G$. Then $\mathrm{p}(W)$ is a way in your sense having a domain of $2\lvert V(G)\rvert-1$ elements. After subtracting $\lvert V(G)\rvert$ we obtain the required upper bound of $\lvert V(G)\rvert-1$ on the "hamiltonicity" (in your sense).